# afford to somebody something?

Tags: word-usage

In *Political Ideals* (1917) the eminent philosopher Bertrand Russell wrote

> The times through which we are passing have afforded to many of us a confirmation of our faith.

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary includes the structure **afford somebody something** with this example:

> The programme affords young people the chance to gain work experience.

Has Russell used the same structure, conveying a similar meaning?

Comment: Interesting.... I think it's the same structure, but the usage of **to** in Bertrand Russell's sentence seems unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: This is the sort of English up with which I cannot put. )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Both structures are standardly available with ditransitive verbs, and have exactly the same meaning. For example:

- I gave the book to the teacher.
- I gave the teacher the book.

Comment: That's right, but some may think that **afford to somebody something** is a standard phrasing while _afford_ seems to be a verb which can't readily afford to have a preposition between itself and an object—I've found only four instances in 20 dictionaries.

Comment: @MvLog  how old were these dictionaries?  Russell wrote this in 1917, and English has somewhat evolved over the past 100 years.  His sentence sounds stilted and old-fashioned to my (modern) ears, but it's in no way *ungrammatical*.

Comment: @Andrew I meant _modern_ dictionaries. All of them cite  **afford somebody something** as the only variant.

Comment: @MvLog be aware that modern English would probably sound intolerably slovenly to many in 1917, particularly educated British gentlemen like Russell, who might have considered the "to" to be *absolutely necessary*.

Comment: Thank you @Colin Fine. Unlike your example and unlike what I've seen in grammar books like _Oxford Practice Grammar - Advanced_, Russell has used the oblique complement 'to many of us' before the direct object 'a confirmation of our faith'. When is this acceptable?

Comment: It's not normally acceptable, @Arham. I think in Russell's example, [heavy element extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) is operating.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same structure. By using [afford](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/afford?s=t), he means *give* or *supply*, which is the same for both examples.

> The times through which we are passing have **given** many of us a confirmation of our faith.
>
> The times through which we are passing have **supplied** many of us a confirmation of our faith.

I also question the use of *to*. When using an indirect pronoun (*us*), *to* is unnecessary because that's what it represents (*to us*). Many learners find asking questions helpful in these situations:

> **Given what?** A confirmation of our faith *(direct object)*.
>
> **To whom?** Many of us *(indirect object)*.

Comment: What about  _"Pile in!" he said to us all with a smile._? Is the **to** unnecessary here?

Comment: @MvLog No, you must say something _to_ someone. If the sentence said _he told us all with a smile_, then yes, _to us_ is unnecessary.

Comment: Then, your generalisation (_using an indirect pronoun (us), to is unnecessary because that's what it represents (to us)_) is wrong. It's complicated part of English—some verbs require a preposition, some don't, some can't.

Comment: @MvLog Nope - when you have a sentence that has _us_ by itself, _to_ is unnecessary because that's what it represents: _to us_. I didn't say that all uses of _us_ never require uses of _to_.